# Try Catch for if script is already running in sheets, prevent a 2nd instance at same time?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that does some basic copy and pasting of data, creates a sheet as a pdf and attaches to an email.I have a button to start it for my less-tech-experienced colleagues embedded in a sheet:

[image]

We share the spreadsheet doc and I'd like to keep it that way for version control. What's the best way to set the script up so that if an instance of the script is already running in the spreadsheet doc it rejects a 2nd attempt until the first one is completed? Some sort of try catch?

I don't think the code is as relevant for this question, here's the beginning of the function in question:

```
function failedSettlementsEmailz() {
  var contacts; 
  var toastMembers="";
....more code...
```

It calls two other functions in my script document that is bound to the Google Sheet spreadsheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

For example in your code have:

```
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
if (lock.tryLock(1000)) { // Wait for 1s
  // Do stuff ...
  lock.releaseLock()
} else {
  // This script is already running, try again later ... 
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten about ``getScriptLock()``. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! Just for anyone else reading, it's lock.releaseLock();

Comment: Correct snippet. Thanks Dylan.

Comment: Note that in case of error or cancel the lock is released anyway when script terminates. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock

Answer (score 1):

I understood that when the script is run by clicking a button, you don't want to run the script more while the script is already running. If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? Please think of this as one of several answers.

In this workaround, I selected to use CacheService. "CacheService allows you to access a cache for short term storage of data." The default expiration is 10 minutes. This is over the maximum execution time of GAS (6 minutes). So I selected this.

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve the key of "script" from CacheService.
2. If there is the key, it means that the script is running.
3. If there is no key, it means that the script is not running.

   1. At this time, put the key of "script" with a value.
   2. The process you want is run.
   3. After the process was finished, the key is removed. This means the script is not running.

#### Sample script :

```
function failedSettlementsEmailz(){
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  if (!cache.get("script")) {
    cache.put("script", "running"); // you can use various value for the value of "running".

    // do something

    cache.remove("script");
  }
}
```

#### Reference :

- [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.